# How to extend a function $f: S \rightarrow N$ to $\bar{f}: \bar{S} \rightarrow N$

Tags: uniform-continuity

I must answer this question: Assume that for the complete metric space $N$, $f: S \rightarrow N$ is a uniformly continuous function defined on a subset $S$ of a metric space $M$. Prove that $f$ extends to a uniformly continuous function $\bar{f}: \bar{S} \rightarrow N$. Then show that $\bar{f}$ is the unique continuous function defined on $\bar{S}$ such that $\bar{f}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in S$.

I start my solution by noting that if $x \in S$, then set  $\bar{f} = f$. I'm not quite sure how to extend for $\bar{S} - S$, though. My intuition says that I should use the fact that $\bar{S} = \lim S$, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it. That still leaves the matter of uniqueness, which I don't have the foggiest clue of how to prove either.

Comment: If $\bar{f}$ is to be continuous, then for a sequence $(x_n)$ in S converging to some $x$ in $\bar{S}$ it should be the case that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$, right? Does this give a hint on how we should define $f(x)$ for this particular $x$? In fact, there is only one reasonable choice. This gives uniqueness (but first prove that this function is well-defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in\bar S\setminus S$, pick a sequence $x_i\in S$ that converges to $x$. Because $f$ is *uniformly* continuous, $f(x_n)$ converges to a finite value $L(x)$. Set $f(x)=L(x)$. Similarly, because $f$ is *uniformly* continuous, $f(x_i)\to L(x)$ for ANY sequence $x_i\to x$ - hence $\bar f$ is unique and by construction continuous. [Edit] It is *uniformly* continuous since its modulus of continuity is the same as that of $f$. [\Edit].

Comment: The last part doesn't seem right. That it is continuous on a closed set does not suffice to claim uniform continuity.

Comment: @A.S., exponential function is continuous on $\mathbb R$, but not uniformly continuous. What you need is compactness.

Comment: It is not entirely striaghtforward to show the extended function is continuous. One should prove this.

Comment: How do I show uniform continuity? I'm unfamiliar with the term "modulus of continuity".